# Can django-mptt render a partial tree with ancestors and descendents from a subset of nodes?

Tags: python, django, django-mptt, mptt

Can django-mptt construct a partial tree from a list of nodes?

Given this complete tree:

```
Cars
  Automatic
    Truck
    Car
  Manual
    Truck
    Car
    Big-rig
```

and given only a subset of nodes, let's say only `["Big-rig", "Car (automatic)"]` can I efficiently render this tree:

```
Cars
  Automatic
    Car
  Manual
    Big-rig
```

?

I know I can descend nodes, moving down through their children. But can I render this partial tree with ancestors, too?